# matlab imfindcircles : how to deal when no circle is found

Tags: matlab, image-processing, simulink

i wish to track a circle with a webcam using `imfindcircles` in a Simulink model. There may be times in the picture when no circle is visible on the image.

I use the following code in a MATLAB function block :

```
    function centreOutput = fcn(image)
    coder.extrinsic('imfindcircles');
    coder.extrinsic('find');
    coder.extrinsic('max');
    temp = 0;
    rayonMax = 0;
    rayons = coder.nullcopy(zeros(1,1));
    centres = coder.nullcopy(zeros(1,2));
    %set the radius
    [centres, rayons] = imfindcircles(image,[20 60],'Sensitivity',0.9,'EdgeThreshold',0.5,'ObjectPolarity','bright');
    rayonMax = min(rayons);
    temp = find(rayons==rayonMax);
    centreOutput = centres(temp,:);
    end
```

my problem is that i get the following error message :

> Size mismatch for MATLAB expression 'rayons'. Expected = 1x1 Actual = 0x0
>   Block MATLAB Function (#41)
>   While executing: State During Action

as i understand it, the dimension of `centres` is not as declared when no circle is found : how could i deal with this when there is no circle to be found (like with a test that would be "if one circle is found...")

Comment: also, why are you initializing `rayons` and `centres`? you wont get faster results (as they are 1x1 or 1x2). Just dont do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it : i just tested the function imfindcircles before assigning its results or not :

```
...
if (isempty(imfindcircles(image,[30 50],'Sensitivity',0.9)))
    centreOutput = [0 0];
else 
[centres, rayons] = imfindcircles(image,[30 50],'Sensitivity',0.9);
    rayonMax = min(rayons);
    temp = find(rayons==rayonMax);
    centreOutput = centres(temp,:);
end
...
```

your answer helped me find the right syntax, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Im glad you got it. Please accept your or mine answer as valid so future lost people know what to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't try this, but what about detecting when that happens? something like

```
function centreOutput = fcn(image)
    coder.extrinsic('imfindcircles');
    coder.extrinsic('find');
    coder.extrinsic('max');
    temp = 0;
    rayonMax = 0;

    %set the radius
    [centres, rayons] = imfindcircles(image,[20 60],'Sensitivity',0.9,'EdgeThreshold',0.5,'ObjectPolarity','bright');

    if (~isempty(centres))
        rayonMax = min(rayons);
        temp = find(rayons==rayonMax);
        centreOutput = centres(temp,:);
    else
        centreOutput=[]; %return empty (or something else, you choose)
    end
end
```

I believe your error may come from initializing variables in that weird way, as you are telling the coder that your variables are 1x1 and 1x2 but they may not.

I am not sure, but this may be a Simulink question. If that is the case, and you need to initialize variables, initialize them as

```
rayons = 0;
centres = [0;0];
```

The computational time is the same and you avoid errors.

Comment: hi,
thanks for your suggestion,
i keep having the same problem as soon as no circle is detected, because the problem comes from the line 

`   [centres, rayons] = imfindcircles(image,[20 60],'Sensitivity',0.9,'EdgeThreshold',0.5,'ObjectPolarity','bright');`

as in this case, imfindcircle returns an 0x0 for 'centres', and that throws the error.. i should find a way to check if imgfindcircles sends a positive result before affecting it to 'centres', but i miss the syntax...

Comment: @raphael even if you declare `rayons` and `centres` the way I told you?